# How do I use Javascript to get the name of the UserControl it is called from?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am trying to replace postbacks with javascript client side processing whenever I can in my aspnet c# 3.5 code so as to improve the user experience.  I am not using any javascript frameworks. I am using vs2008.

I have a usercontrol .ascx file  with a dropdown list and button which is used in three places on my main screen.

I had been doing a postback on OnSelectedIndexChanged for the dropdown list.

I don’t need to postback every time though, so I tried putting in a javascript function in the usercontrol to check the item selected and only do a postback if it starts with ‘-‘.

However the name of the elements I need to $get in my javascript function depend on the name of the usercontrol instance which calls it, and I need to get that name at runtime, for example :  uc1_ ddlLocations  and  uc1_ btnPostBack.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ddlChange(this) { 
var loc = $get("GetTheUserControlNameAndInsertHere_ddlLocations"); 
if (loc.value.substring(0,1)=='-' )  
{ 
var btn = $get("GetTheUserControlNameAndInsertHere_btnPostBack ");  
btn.click(); 
}
</script>
```

How do I do this? Can someone suggest a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Does the UserControl itself know if a postback is necessary?  Could a "needsPostback" parameter be passed to ddlChange()?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. For the UserControl to figure out if it needs a postback it need to do a postback.

Comment: @Mike, @Lill: the function is determining if the postback is necessary, not the ddl itself. The ddl will either always do a postback ("AutoPostBack=True") or never ("AutoPostBack=false"). He's trying to insert some conditional logic to lower bandwidth cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could determine the UserControl name by parsing it out of the ddl name.  Please keep in mind that I didn't debug the parsing logic, it might be off slightly :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function ddlChange(ddl) 
  { 

    if (ddl.value.substring(0,1)=='-' )  
    { 
      var prefixEndLoc = ddl.id.lastIndexOf("_");
      var prefix = ddl.id.subString(0,prefixEndLoc);
      var btn = $get(prefix + "_btnPostBack ");  
      btn.click(); 
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Just going to add: 

1. need to have: dlLocations.Attributes.Add "OnChange", "javascript:locChange(this);");
in the pageload code behind to pass the javascript parm (ddl), 
and 
2. I added an 
else ddl.blur(); 
to remove focus from the dropdownlist item selected. Would have been confusing to the user otherwise. 

Thanks, JustLoren!

Answer (score 0):

use the ClientID of you control and give it to your javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ClientID to a Javascript variable from the code behind.

Use that Variable in javascript call to get the element.